# Get attribute of XML tag using xml_parse_into_struct in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<site>
    <pages>
        <page number="1">main page</page>
        <page number="2">about</page>
        <page number="3">contacts</page>
    </pages>
</site>
```

I need to print 3 parameters with the format `type : number : value`.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('file.xml');
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

foreach ($vals as $val) {
    print(" {$val["type"]} : {$val["number"]} : {$val["value"]}<br><br>\n");
}
```

This prints the type and the value, but not the number. How can I print the "number" attribute of an XML tag?

Comment: Don't use this API it is only here for backwards compatibility. Use one the three: DOM, XMLReader or SimpleXML.

Comment: @AlexisKing, thanks for formatting!

Comment: @ThW, I see, thanks.

Trying SimpleXML, like this:
`$xml_str = file_get_contents('file.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
$pages = $xml->xpath('*/page');

foreach($pages as $page) {
    echo $page['number'], ': ', $page['value'], "\n";
}`

Now attributes 'number' printed, but values are not...
What need to be changed here?

Comment: `$page['value']` would mean an attribute `value`. Just cast `$page` to string for the text content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug this, you could just add in `print_r( $val );` into the foreach loop. What you'll see there is that there is an `attributes` array in the `$val`, which contains the number. So, change the foreach loop to be something like:

```
foreach ($vals as $val) {
    if ( 'PAGE' !== $val['tag'] ) {
        continue;
    }
  print(" {$val['type']} : {$val['attributes']['NUMBER']} : {$val['value']}<br><br>\n");
}
```

And then you should have it. Although, I'm not sure if you want `$val['type']`, but you might want `$val['tag']`. `$val['type']` will be either `open`, `closed`, or `complete`, which refers to the tag as its being parsed. `$val['tag']` will be `SITE`, `PAGES`, or `PAGE`, with the bit of xml that you referenced in the post.

Comment: Yes, {$val['attributes']['NUMBER']} get the attributes.
(BTW, I have been trying {$val['attributes']['number']}, but upper case is important here!)
Thank you!